# Node comments don't show up in view when they should

Tags: 7, views, comments

I'm creating a view that lists full view of nodes.

These nodes have comments and the comments are showing up as they should on their node page, but not when they're listed in the view.

"Display Comments" option is checked in Views in the row style settings.

Here is the exported view, it may be helpful. There is a second Block display where I list Full nodes, showing comments is checked.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'flickr_images';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Flickr Images';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'See What Others Are Sharing';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'grid';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['id'] = 'field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['table'] = 'field_data_field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['field'] = 'field_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['element_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'flickr_thumb',
  'image_link' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_image']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Global: PHP */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['id'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['field'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['use_php_setup'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['php_output'] = '<a href="#" class="photo-container" data-reveal-id="<?php print $data->_field_data[\'nid\'][\'entity\']->field_flickr_id[\'und\'][0][\'safe_value\']; ?>">  
  <div>
    <div class="photo-tweet photo-container"><?php print $data->field_field_image[0][\'rendered\']; ?></div>
  </div>
</a>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['use_php_click_sortable'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['php']['php_click_sortable'] = '';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'flickr_image' => 'flickr_image',
);

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['view_mode'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['comments'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$translatables['flickr_images'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('See What Others Are Sharing'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Block'),
);
```

Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: I'm able to get the comments in views 7.x-3.3. Which version of views module you're using. It would be better if you put the exported the view.

Comment: I use 7.x-3.7, I updated the question with the exporter view

Comment: Have you tried create node display with Display Suite module?

Comment: I'm not using DS on this site currently and I wrote a very custom template for the node, turning on DS and using the DS one column layout for example will result in a lot of redoing. I might do that anyway, because there doesnt seem to be a solution for this problem

Comment: @milkovsky I actually set the display mode to Display Suite from Content and it works! I didn't have to write new templates at all. If you put this in as a proper answer I'll mark it as a good answer.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. I added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create node display with [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module.

And then set the display mode to Display Suite from Content

Comment: I didn't have to create the node display with DS, it was good as it is. The only thing I had to do is turn on DS and switch the view format to Display Suite and not Comment. I still had to turn on display comments in the Display Suite format settings, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Usually the comment are displayed in the "Links" display. Go to your content type and in Manage display tab, make sure that you have the "Links" field enabled. If so, you sould have something like this in your views (after saving):

> Read more | "TITLE OF THE NODE" | 2 comments("x comments") | Add
>   new comment

Comment: There is no Links field in Manage display tab

Comment: I can enable the 'Display Links' on the view row settings, but that doesnt list the comments. 'Display Comments' doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Node comments will not show up as you are displaying fields instead of Nodes (named Content in Views). The setting display comments is in effect when you show Content in Views.

If you switch to show: Content instead of Fields you get the line saying something like "1 comment Add new comment".

If you still want to use fields to display your data I suggest you add the fields 
**Content: Add comment link** and **Content: Comment count** to create your own comment information to the node.

Comment: I'm using Content in the second view display, but fields on the first and the problem is with the second view display. Sorry if I didn't make that clearer.

Comment: Aha, I see now what you mean.